# Unity UI RectTransform Width Height is not correct

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, height, width

I'm trying to get corrent top and bottom position for my object. I'm using recttransform for width and height.

```
object.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position.y + r.rect.height / 2; //top
object.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position.y - r.rect.height / 2; //bottom
```

Result 
[This is What i get i try to drawline positions in x-axis (red and black lines)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOjPS.jpg)

Why is this happening? What should i do to get correct positions?

[I'm trying to explain little more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9rf6.jpg)

Comment: What code do you use to draw the line?

Comment: Trying to control values that is correct or not.

Comment: Okan, you may need to show us the full code, if you want a proper answer.

Comment: 'RectTransform r;
        r = this.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        float top = Parent.GetChild(0).GetComponent<RectTransform>().position.y + r.rect.height / 2;
        float bottom = Parent.GetChild(0).GetComponent<RectTransform>().position.y - r.rect.height / 2;'

Comment: I'm using "Panel" . And its another panel's child.

Comment: if you are changing parent make sure you `.setParent(newparent, false)`